# Binding ArcGIS Esri SDK in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, arcgis

In [this thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/856/help-wrapping-third-party-jar-for-mono-for-android/p1) on the Xamarin forums I found [instructions](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/35169/#Comment_35169) and a [sample application](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/35173/#Comment_35173) on how to make a **Java Bindings Library** in Xamarin for Esri's ArcGIS Android sdk.

I downloaded the sample project and added the 10.1.1 esri `.jar` files and the two `.so` files and set the properties in Visual Studio 2013 to the settings noted in the parenthesis below. I'm trying to run this on both a real device (Samsung S3) and the Google emulator(ARM).

In the Core project under *Jars*

- ArcGIS_Android.jar (EmbeddedJar)
- jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.5.jar (EmbeddedReferenceJar)
- jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.5.jar (EmbeddedReferenceJar)

In the Android Project under *Assets*

- armeabi\libruntimecore_java.so (AndroidNativeLibrary)
- armeabi-v7a\libruntimecore_java.so (AndroidNativeLibrary)

I am able to successfully build the project and run it. *However it crashes spectacularly at run time when I try to new up a MapView in the MainActivity*:

```
var esriMap = new MapView(this);
```

If I trace the exception I'm able to narrow it down to this line in the `MapView` constructor:

```
    JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (Handle, 
                                 class_ref,
                                 id_ctor_Landroid_content_Context_, 
                                 new JValue (p0));
```

Which I can then trace the exception to here:

```
internal static IntPtr class_ref 
{
 get { return JNIEnv.FindClass ("com/esri/android/map/MapView", ref java_class_handle); }
}
```

This is the exception that is thrown:
[image: Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError exception]

I did use the Android Debug Bridge to check out the log and here are my results (filtered):

Command: **adb logcat MonoDroid-Debugger:D monodroid-gc:D Mono:W dalvikvm:W mono-rt:V *:S**

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
W/MonoDroid-Debugger(11905): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8839,server=y,emb
edding=1
W/MonoDroid-Debugger(11905): Accepted stdout connection: 50
W/monodroid-gc(11905): GREF GC Threshold: 46800
W/Mono    (11905): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
W/Mono    (11905): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
W/Mono    (11905): The request to load the assembly System.Core v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v3.5.0.0
W/Mono    (11905): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
W/Mono    (11905): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
W/dalvikvm(11905): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
W/dalvikvm(11905):              in Ltestarcgisforandroid/MainActivity;.n_onCreate:(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V (GetMethodID)
W/dalvikvm(11905): Pending exception is:
E/dalvikvm(11905): VM aborting
E/mono-rt (11905): Stacktrace:
E/mono-rt (11905):
E/mono-rt (11905):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
E/mono-rt (11905):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.wrapper_native_0x40b2efd1 (intptr,intptr,string,string) <IL 0x0004c, 0xffffffff>
E/mono-rt (11905):   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_intptr__this___intptr_intptr_string_string (intptr,intptr,string,string) <IL 0x00063, 0xffffff
ff>
E/mono-rt (11905):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.GetMethodID (intptr,string,string) [0x00042] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a
1e3982a/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:157
E/mono-rt (11905):   at Java.Lang.Throwable.get_Message () [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a1e3982a/source/monodroi
d/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Java.Lang.Throwable.cs:231
E/mono-rt (11905):   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_object__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>
E/mono-rt (11905):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
E/mono-rt (11905):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.60a3ae85-654e-4b68-b823-e9fd8b83b17b (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00034, 0x000a8>
E/mono-rt (11905):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.60a3ae85-654e-4b68-b823-e9fd8b83b17b (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00023, 0xffffffff>
E/mono-rt (11905):
E/mono-rt (11905): =================================================================
E/mono-rt (11905): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
E/mono-rt (11905): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
E/mono-rt (11905): used by your application.
E/mono-rt (11905): =================================================================
E/mono-rt (11905):
W/MonoDroid-Debugger(11961): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8839,server=y,emb
edding=1
W/MonoDroid-Debugger(11961): Accepted stdout connection: -1
F/MonoDroid-Debugger(11961): Error accepting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:8840): Address already in use
W/MonoDroid-Debugger(11978): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8839,server=y,emb
edding=1
W/MonoDroid-Debugger(11978): Accepted stdout connection: -1
F/MonoDroid-Debugger(11978): Error accepting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:8840): Address already in use
W/dalvikvm(12023): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 505: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalFilesDirs (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/io/File;
W/MonoDroid-Debugger(12217): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8841,server=y,emb
edding=1
W/MonoDroid-Debugger(12217): Accepted stdout connection: 50
W/monodroid-gc(12217): GREF GC Threshold: 46800
W/Mono    (12217): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
W/Mono    (12217): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
W/Mono    (12217): The request to load the assembly System.Core v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v3.5.0.0
W/Mono    (12217): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
W/Mono    (12217): The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong - I've tried running/compiling this at both Android API Levels 17 & 19 (the author of the sample used API Level 17).

I tried running the solution in Xamarin Studio (instead of VS2013) and I got a different exception:

> no method with name='requestRender' signature='(Z)V' in class
>   Lcom/esri/android/map/MapSurface;

Here's the stack trace:

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='requestRender' signature='(Z)V' in class Lcom/esri/android/map/MapSurface;
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a1e3982a/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:895
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a1e3982a/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:272
  at Com.Esri.Android.Map.MapView..ctor (Android.Content.Context) [0x00109] in c:\Workspace\VisualStudio\ArcGISForAndroid\ArcGISForAndroid\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Esri.Android.Map.MapView.cs:109
  at TestArcGISForAndroid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00026] in c:\Workspace\VisualStudio\ArcGISForAndroid\TestArcGISForAndroid\MainActivity.cs:21
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a1e3982a/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-17/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2119
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.26ff0a5e-0708-4e2c-8084-a668e6c87b45 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
  at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='requestRender' signature='(Z)V' in class Lcom/esri/android/map/MapSurface;
  at at com.esri.android.map.MapSurface.nativeMapCreate(Native Method)
  at at com.esri.android.map.MapSurface.a(Unknown Source)
  at at com.esri.android.map.MapSurface.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at at com.esri.android.map.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
  at at com.esri.android.map.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at at testarcgisforandroid.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
  at at testarcgisforandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
 at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
  at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? Can you please post the solution, if so.

Comment: No, never solved. We're waiting for ESRI to release the Xamarin bindings.

Answer (score 0):

need add libruntimecore_java.so to the folder libs\armeabi and libs\armeabi-v7a
and set the file property to "AndroidNativeLibrary"

it can copy from eclipse android project folder libs